# How To Create Minimal Win32 C Program with no Windows APIs in Import Table with Visual Studio

Tags: c, visual-studio, winapi

I'm trying to replicate a bug from a legacy VB4 application. The EXE itself doesn't have any Windows APIs in the import table; instead they are all loaded from the VB runtime DLL.

I want to recreate a similar scenario but using C in Visual Studio. Later I will create my equivalent of the runtime DLL with Windows API imports, however the first step is to ensure no Windows APIs are in the import table within my EXE.

So far I have removed nearly everything from import table by using /SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE, removing all .LIB from Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies , and setting runtime library to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd).

However kernel32.dll APIs are still in the import table. While I realise /SUBSYSTEM:NATIVE is typically for drivers, I'm not sure if that's what I need to use, however I couldn't get a minimal application (i.e. one that launches, then exits without crashing) to compile with that option.

If I use Linker -> Input -> Ignore All Default Libraries -> Yes (/NODEFAULTLIB) I get the following errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Suppression State
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup  Minimalist  C:\Users\chentiangemalc\source\repos\Minimalist\Minimalist\LINK 1       
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __RTC_CheckEsp referenced in function _main  Minimalist  C:\Users\chentiangemalc\source\repos\Minimalist\Minimalist\Minimalist.obj   1       
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __RTC_InitBase   Minimalist  C:\Users\chentiangemalc\source\repos\Minimalist\Minimalist\Minimalist.obj   1       
Error   LNK2001 unresolved external symbol __RTC_Shutdown   Minimalist  C:\Users\chentiangemalc\source\repos\Minimalist\Minimalist\Minimalist.obj   1
```

The code I'm trying to compile has no includes and is just:

```
int main()
{
}
```

Comment: You'll have to go lower level and not use `main` at all. Set an explicit `/ENTRY` that goes to your replacement `main`. You'll also have to set the compiler options to avoid things like stack checking (which is where the `__RTC_...` references are coming from).

Comment: Using /MT is wrong, that links the code that is normally in the "runtime DLL" into your program.  You'll have to do it like VB4 did it and use /MD.  And now it is no effort at all to avoid any such link dependencies.

Comment: after further testing I found /MT or /MD both result in no imports and the same file size as long as I don't call any C runtime functions.

Comment: The only difference now at initial execution is I see my app calls ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart -> KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk  -> imported DLL function; where as the VB4 app goes straight ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart -> imported DLL function, skipping over KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk (At least based on WinDbg stack trace with breakpoint set on imported DLL function starting)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raymond Chen's comment sent me in the right direction. To create this program in Visual Studio 2019 used

1. New Project | C++ Console Program
2. Renamed .cpp to .c (If you want to create a C program)
3. Replaced code with custom entry point:

   int myMain()
   {
   }
4. In Project properties | **C/C++ Code Generation** set **Basic Runtime checks** to nothing (erase the text), set **Runtime library** to Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd) for debug build or Multi-threaded (/MT) for release build, set **Security Check** to Disable Security Check (/GS-)
5. In Project properties | **Linker** | **Input** | remove everything from **Additional  Dependencies** and set **Ignore All Default Libraries** to **Yes (/NODEFAULTLIB)**
6. In Project properties | **Linker** | **Advanced** set Entry point to myMain

You now have a program with a completely empty import table.

Comment: yes, only for what is rename *.cpp* to *.c* ? this is not need

Comment: it may not be needed but I wanted to create C program.

Comment: what is *c* program ? really *exe* is *exe* which language you use not play role here. we can do this and with *c++* too